# Convert base 64 string image to image python

Tags: python

I use this code to convert base64 string to image:

```
getbase64Data = request.GET.get('base64Data')
filename = 'demo.jpg'
f =  open(filename, 'wb') 
f.write(getbase64Data.decode('base64'))
f.close()
```

But i get invalid img file.Any help appriciated thanks!

Comment: Are you certain that the result of fetching `"base64Data"` actually is a base64-encoded JPEG image file?

Comment: I certain i use jpg img to encode

Comment: Can you show the encoding command as well, so we have the full image to image process.  Otherwise, this type of question almost always end with the OP discovering that they aren't starting with what they think they're starting with.

Comment: some browser truncate GET requests that are too many chars?

Comment: Can you maybe put somewhere (1) the original image file, (2) the base-64 data you think should be being used, (3) what's actually in `getbase64Data` after your first line executes, and (4) what ends up in `demo.jpg`?

Comment: I mean, put them somewhere where SO readers can access them?